# Display slows down on external monitor

Tags: windows-10, display, lenovo-laptop, external-display, displayport

I'm not really sure how to best phrase the subject, but:

The situation is I have a laptop connected to an external monitor. When I use the laptop's own display, everything is fine. But today, I've found that when I use the monitor, the screen just... slows down. That is, scrolling in a window is laggy, the desktop animations are jerky (eg when minimising and maximising a window), the responsiveness when typing this post is laggy, etc. This is all in the Windows desktop, not games or whatever.

The laptop is a Lenovo X1 Extreme running Win 10 Pro 1903, and the monitor is a 7-year-old Dell P2715Q 4K unit, connected via a DisplayPort-to-USB3 adapter. GPU-Z doesn't report any issues with the card, as far as I can tell, and Windows also seems to be working properly. The monitor has been having issues for some time; often it refuses to wake from sleep unless I physically unplug the power cord and plug it back in again.

Any ideas what could be causing this, and what I can do to fix it? Is it time to just bite the bullet, and get a new monitor?

ETA: Windows still shows the monitor running at 4K/60Hz, so the USB port seems to be supplying enough bandwidth.

---

ETA2: the connection is actually Thunderbolt, behind a USB-C port. I've also found that everything works correctly if I duplicate the display on both the laptop and the monitor. If I then switch back to using only the monitor, it continues working for a few seconds, and then slows down again.

Device Manager also doesn't show any problems, and all my drivers are up to date as far as I know.

Comment: My bet is the USB adapter can't keep up with the 4K resolution

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I've actually been using this setup for a few months; it only went bad today.

Comment: I see. Worth putting into the question.

Comment: Hm... I have a similar issue with my Lenovo X1 Extreme. Makes me wonder if the problem is with something in the laptop design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A BIOS update showed up in Lenovo Vantage a couple of days after I posted this question. Installing that seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is no "problem."  The *issue* the USB speed.

Are you using you laptops USBv3 port and is your USB to DP adapter USBv3?  There are USBv3 versions, which are 10x faster than USBv2.  However, I have not used a USBv3 adapter and cannot say how much better they are.  What I do know, is the USBv2 versions simply arent even close to fast enough for anything other than writing emails, documents, spreadsheets, etc.  I would strongly feel USBv3, even though they are 10x faster, wouldnt be fast enough.  Running at 4K resolution isnt helping either.

Comment: Yes, it's all USB3. I was using this setup for a few months without any problems. It only went bad today.

Comment: @HongOoi You didnt make that clear in your question.  Obviously, double check that the USB port is running at v3.  I havent used these adapters in a *very long* time, but in the past, the were known for going bad.  Perhaps this adapter has gone bad as well.

Comment: Per the edit, Windows still reports that the monitor is running at 60Hz, which would imply the port is supplying enough bandwidth

Comment: @HongOoi That is incorrect.  60Hz the refresh rate, which has has ***NOTHING*** to do with the bandwidth.